# How to get the time intervals and total time from a machine recorded minute to minute timestamps data sheet

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

This is Nikhil.

Here is where I got struck for days, Please help anyone.

I'm having a data of time stamps for every minute in the month.
And there is a corresponding data as well.

Based on the data, i need the time intervals and total operational time and total non operational time in excel.

[image]

in this excel file, input table is what im having and output data table is what im desired for....

Thanks you
Nikhil

**Edit:**
Thank you so much for the first answer,,,

But actually i asked half of the question only to made it understandable.

Now the real problem is - **I want the time intervals which are in between the actual shift timings (That are 7:00, 15:00, 23:00).**
So that I can calculate the individual shift working and non working hrs.

Please go though the second image's output format.
[Second image with updated output shift timings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCY7P.png)

Thanks for your valuable time.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done with formulas:

[image: Example of Sheet Conversion]

Identifies locations where "Operational/Non Operational" sections begin, then sorts them into final report with array formulas.

See link: (to note, array formulas do not work correctly in Google Sheets, must be viewed in excel. )

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TnYBaVqoH9GbqSOrJhamOVOeJFy5gmQ0/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=113383321265118626810&rtpof=true&sd=true

Array Formula Images:
[image: Section Identify]
[image: Time Example]
[image: Array Example]

Comment: Thankyou very much for the fast reply, But I need something more, pls go through the Edited part of the question.

Comment: Added section that calculates shift totals. [**Workbook Can Be Found Here**](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1q_ZZz5S0CmfiZLy_RqeCv_7-IOFqC3tH/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=113383321265118626810&rtpof=true&sd=true)